# Residential society

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

In a residential society, there are 120 people who either consume only tea or only coffee. Of those 120 people, 25 are children (which includes male as well as female children), and 78 consume tea. The number of males who consume coffee plus the number of children who consume tea is equal to 61. The number of females who consume tea plus the number of children who consume coffee is equal to 73. The total number of males is 14 less than the number of females in the society.

Find the number of females in the society who consume coffee?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this appears to be a [textbook math problem.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic) A good math problem, surely, but maybe not actually "puzzleish.") Am I missing something?

Comment: @Chowzen you could argue that there’s some logical deduction involved here too — it’s definitely along the same veins as the other puzzles that Sam posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so let’s start with

> There are 14 fewer males than females and 120 total residents. This means there are 53 males and 67 females. Further, there are 95 adults and 25 children, as well as 78 tea drinkers and 42 coffee drinkers. You’ll notice that children who drink tea plus children who drink coffee equals total children equals 25. So male coffee drinkers + female tea drinkers + children = 61+73=134, then male coffee drinkers + female tea drinkers = 134 - 25 = 109. Therefore male tea drinkers + female coffee drinkers = 120 - 109 = 11. But male tea drinkers = 78 minus female tea drinkers, so 78 - female tea drinkers + female coffee drinkers = 11. Rearranging this, 78-11 = female tea drinkers - female coffee drinkers = 67. Further, we know that female tea drinkers + female coffee drinkers = 67. Therefore we subtract these two equations to find that 2 x female coffee drinkers = 0, and so **no females in the society consume coffee**.

This means that:

> All 67 females drink tea, no females drink coffee, 11 males drink tea, and 42 males drink coffee. Also, 6 children consume coffee (all of them male) and so 19 children consume tea.

Comment: Thanks again nice work. What was the trigger to add male coffee drinkers + female tea drinkers + children ? Can you give some insight on it?

Comment: @sam The children don’t really matter to this question. What we really care about is the male/female and coffee/tea split, because the adult/children split is irrelevant. I just noticed that since we don’t know the number of male children vs female children, adding those two numbers together gives us a number we do know (total children), which we can then remove to give us a workable equation in terms of the splits we actually care about.